# Is the EFI partition and GPT necessary with less than 2 TiB?

Tags: partitioning, gpt, efi, system-reserved-partition

I have a 1 TB external USB hard drive that is GUID partitioned with a 100MB FAT32 EFI partition.

The thing is that its a *1* terabyte drive. From what I'm aware, the limit is at *2* tebibytes (TiB). Therefore, the GPT isn't necessary, and MBR could be used instead.

TL;DR: *What would happen if I delete the EFI partition and reformat as MBR partition table on an external drive not booted from?*

Comment: "The thing is that its a 1.5 terabyte drive. From what I'm aware, the limit is at 2 terabytes. So LBA with GPT isn't necessary."  Why are you asking if you already know the answer?

Comment: Related: [2TB external drive, disk initialization: MBR or GPT](http://superuser.com/questions/192300/2tb-external-drive-disk-initialization-mbr-or-gpt), and [What are the differences between MBR vs GPT vs any other partition scheme?](http://superuser.com/questions/324525/what-are-the-differences-between-mbr-vs-gpt-vs-any-other-partition-scheme).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What would happen if I delete the EFI partition and reformat as MBR partition table on an external drive not booted from?

Nothing. It would still just work.

---

But you do seem to mix EFI and GPT, so let me give a longer answer:

[MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) is a very old way of partitioning drives on a PC. It only allowed for four *primary* partitions, or, with a workaround, for 3 primary and several more *"extended"* partitions. It also tops out at 2.0 TiB (2<sup>32</sup> 512 byte sectors), or 2.20 TB.

The GUID Partition Table (aka GPT), on the other hand, is a more modern way of dividing a drive into partitions. It allows for drives larger than 2 TiB, and it allows for way more partitions (up to 128 specifically).

There is nothing which stops you from selecting either method on a small enough drive. Both methods are valid. Any modern computer should be able to handle both of them, either via the BIOS or EUFI.

---

There are three catches here though:

- If you use ancient software (e.g. Windows XP, which came out before the GPT scheme was created), then it will not understand GPT.
- If you use a old BIOS, then it may not understand GPT. (A modern BIOS *should* understand it, though there are quite a few which fail).
- If you partition a drive larger then 2.0 TiB with the MBR scheme, you will not be able to access anything past the 2 TiB mark. Your 1 TB drive, however, is small enough that this does not matter.